# How to retrieve records for multiple tables on multiple pages with same ng-controller?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, controllers

> I have 2 dashboards with  index.php
>   1.offers.php 2.terminatio.php on offers page i have below script with myCtrl controller to fetch records of offers table. Its working.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);  
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/companyJson.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.names = $scope.names = response.data.service;});
        getInfo();    
        function getInfo() {
            $http.post('getTask.php').success(function(data) {
                $scope.details = data;
            })
        }
```

> Now, same code I am using on termination page

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);  
app.controller('termination', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/companyJson.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.names = $scope.names = response.data.service;
    });
    getInfo();    
    function getInfo() {
        $http.post('gettermination.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.details = data;
    })
}
```

> on both page I'm using different controllers. and on index.php I called
>   ng-app. I'm able to fetch only offers script. termination's script is
>   not working.please help me with the same I'm totally new in angular

Comment: The problem might also be with the gettermination.php script, have you tested it alone using something like postman? Also why are you doing a post to something that is returning data, without sending anything? That is usually  done through get request.

Comment: its working on postman